# How to modify a column using column number instead of column name?

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({"col": [1, 2, 3]})
df['col'] = 2 * df['col']
```

In the above example, I can modify a column in place using its name.

I could modify a column using the column number (0 in this case) as follows. But the following approach is rather verbose.

```
df[df.columns[0]] = 2 * df[df.columns[0]]
```

What is the most succinct way to modify a column in place?

Answer (score 1):

`iloc` is a little bit shorter:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col": [1, 2, 3]})
df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0] * 2
df
Out[1]: 
   col
0    2
1    4
2    6
```